# Spring @Autowire when using multi-level interfaces

Tags: java, spring, interface, autowired

I want to find a solution to configure my spring to support multi-level inheritance of interfaces.The considered scenario is as follow:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        TextEditor te = (TextEditor) ctx.getBean("textEditor");
        te.spellCheck();
    }
```

//--------------------

```
@Component
public class TextEditor {
    @Autowired
    private SpellChecker1 spellChecker;
    public void spellCheck() {
        spellChecker.checkSpelling();
    }
}
```

//--------------------

```
public interface SpellChecker1 extends SpellChecker2{
}
```

//--------------------

```
public interface SpellChecker2 {
    public void checkSpelling();
}
```

//--------------------

```
@Service
public class SpellCheckerImpl implements SpellChecker2 {
    public SpellCheckerImpl() {
        System.out.println("Inside SpellChecker constructor.");
    }
    @Override
    public void checkSpelling() {
        System.out.println("Inside checkSpelling.");
    }
}
```

//--------------------
Also, my Beans.xml file is contain:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
 <context:annotation-config/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.test"/>
<bean id="textEditor" class="com.mycompany.test.TextEditor" > 
</bean>
</beans>
```

//**************The following error is issued when running the the MainClass**************

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'textEditor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mycompany.test.SpellChecker1 com.mycompany.test.TextEditor.spellChecker; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.mycompany.test.SpellChecker1] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

Comment: There is no class implementing `SpellChecker1`, thus the bean container cannot inject an instance of `Spellchecker2`, hence the exception.

Comment: @Turing85: Many thanks. It makes perfect sense.

Comment: correction to my first comment: "*... bean container cannot inject an instance of `Spellchecker2`..."* should read "*... bean container cannot inject an instance of `Spellchecker1`...*"